# Using Cast.js with Meteor

Tags: json, meteor, jquery-isotope

I'm working with [Ben McMahen's](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/45711238911/create-beautiful-grid-layouts-with-cast-js) example of intigrating [cast.js](https://github.com/bmcmahen/cast) with Meteor and I'm having some trouble figuring out excatly how it is suppose to work. His demo was built with Meteor, however the instructions in his blog and on github are a bit unclear to me. I'm trying to do a similar layout as his demo, but instead of rendering videos it will render photos. I'm hoping someone can help show me where I'm going wrong.

First, my HTML template is as follows:

```
{{#constant}}
  <div id="cast"></div>
{{/constant}}
```

My client code is:

```
   function renderTemplate(obj){
    return '<img class="img-rounded" src="' + obj.photo + '>';
}

Template.cast.rendered = function(){

    var el = document.getElementById('#cast');

    var mycast = cast(el);

    mycast.draw();

    this.handle = Meteor.autorun(function(){
        var photo = picture.find().fetch();
        mycast
            .data(photo, '_id')
            .dynamic(150, 150, 10, 10);
    });
}
```

My collection is:

```
Photos = new Meteor.Collection('picture');
```

**Edit:**

The new changes on 0.5.1 work great fix most of the errors I had with cast.js, however I'm still having some trouble rendering the data into each template.

First off, so you know how my data is structured, when I run `db.picture.findOne();` in mongoDB the data renders as:

```
   {
        "id" : "999999999999999",
        "from" : {
            "name" : "Seano314",
            "id" : "99999999"
        },
        "picture" : "https://photoSmall.jpg",
        "source" : "https://photoLarge.jpg",
        "height" : 540,
        "width" : 720
}
```

Right now I'm getting an error of `Cannot set property 'rendered' of undefined` from the `Template.cast.rendered` function. I'm not sure if I'm getting this error because I'm calling my data wrong or if there something else going on that I'm unaware of. Any thoughts on how what might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, here is a link to the [demo](http://cast.meteor.com) and a link to [app.js](https://github.com/bmcmahen/cast/blob/master/dist/app.js).

Comment: "and require this script in your html page." Where are you doing that? You would want to include  <script src=LOCATION OF FILE></script> tag at the top of whatever html file you are using, probably the index.html file

Comment: I've tried adding the file in both the client and the server, however neither worked. Correct me if I'm wrong however I thought meteor automatically source the app.js file. Nonetheless I included source tags to it in `<head>` however it didn't work.

Comment: mind throwing the code up in a github repo?

Comment: Hey guys. I'll give this a close look tomorrow morning and we can get it sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for trying my little library. I haven't touched Meteor in a long time (nor this library) so hopefully I can still be of some help in getting this working.

First off, you need to include the `app.js` file (which I've renamed to `cast.js` in the repo) in the Meteor client-side code and *not* the server-side code. This might explain why you are getting the `window not defined` error. As you can see in the end of the code you posted, `cast.js` is attempting to attach its name to the global `window` object... thus making it a global variable. If window doesn't exist (which it doesn't on the server) then you'll get this error.

Second, if you are using the standalone build `cast.js` you do *not* need to use the `require('cast')` statement. The cast constructor is already defined as `cast`.

Other than that, things look pretty good. I've updated the [cast.js repo](https://github.com/bmcmahen/cast) which some Meteor specific instructions. I would also recommend using the updated `cast.js` file in the `dist` folder.

**EDIT:**

Okay, your new error is a result of how Meteor loads its scripts. For starters, you need to ensure that your script *only* loads on the client and that it loads *after* the dom has loaded. This explains your current error: `document.body` is undefined because the dom hasn't loaded yet! And this is because Meteor loads all of its scripts inside of the `<head>`... whereas, in most web apps that I write, I load the script at the end of the `<body>` tag.

For a fix: 
Put the `cast.js` file in the `public` folder so that it isn't auto-bundled by Meteor.
Then load your script once the DOM has loaded:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.startup(function() {
     $('head').append('<script src="/cast.js"></script>');
  });

}
```

You might run into some issues doing this, in which your template runs before `cast` is loaded... but it might be fine. I can also do a small fix in the lib itself so that it doesn't check for `translate3d` support until the dom has loaded.

**EDIT:**
Version 0.5.1 of Cast.js will now properly load simply by including it in Meteor's client-code. Also note that the API has changed fairly significantly (for the better, imo).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, bento. I'm still getting two errors of `Cannot set property 'rendered' of undefined` in the `Meteor.autorun` function and `Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null`, which looks like the root of the problem. The second error is coming from line 601 in `cast.js`. Any thoughts on what might cause this? Also, just FYI, I'm using Iron Router instead of the Meteor Router with my app, which might have something to do with this.

Comment: Very strange. This must have something to do with how Meteor loads scripts... which is a behaviour that has perhaps changed since I last used it. I'll try to install the latest version of Meteor to see if I can get it running.

Comment: The new changes on 0.5.1 of Cast.js worked great to fix the second error, however I'm still getting the `Cannot set property'rendered' of undndefined` error. If it is not too much trouble, do you have a working meteor example you can post in github? I think the problem might be coming from how I'm calling the data, however I'm having trouble figuring out where the fix needs to be. I'll update my question above so you can see the full code I'm working with.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help, Bento. The example works like a charm.